# How does JVM decide to extend memory or do a GC?

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection

I am using a JBoss instance that has a start memory of 4 GB and a max memory of 12 GB. My question is - how does the JVM decide when to extend memory (from 4GB higher) vs when to force a full GC? The reason I ask is because I am watching the memory profile of the JVM and in one instance I noticed it increased the memory ceiling from 4GB to a higher value to accommodate the memory growth demand and in another case it decided to perform a full GC to bring the used memory lower. Any understanding on this?

Comment: Asking the operating system for more memory is a relatively expensive operation.  I believe it only happens after a full gc does not result in enough memory being available for a given operation.

Answer (score 0):

You did not say what JVM you were using, but to my knowledge they all grow the heap to accommodate more objects. It is very likely that something else caused the full gc.
If you have the 12 GB available (which you should if you allow the JVM to grow) then I would also recommend to set Xms=12GB as well. This allows you to easier understand what generation sizes you want to have without the need to deal with heap resizing.